# Searching for an underscore with LIKE

Tags: postgresql, sql-like

I am using a Postgres server and am having difficulty with XML data types.
There seems to be limited information online about Postgres and XML.

I am trying to insert a column of XML data into a temporary table where the Location node contains an underscore, using something similar to LIKE in SQL

```
<Country>
    <ID>813</ID>
    <Location>IB_202</Loction>
</Country>
```

I am using this SQL query to get the data

```
SELECT CAST(xpath('/Country/Location/text()', penDetails) as text[])
FROM "dbSystemCheck".tbl_countryitems
WHERE personId = 314
AND CAST(xpath('/Country/Location/text()', penDetails) LIKE '%[_]%'
LIMIT 10
```

The temporary table is set up the same as the original data table, I am looking to just split the locations.

I have read that underscores need to be escaped hence the []

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have read that underscores need to be escaped hence the []

The square brackets have no special meaning in a SQL `LIKE` statement. If you want to escape the underscore you need to specify an ESCAPE character:

```
AND CAST(xpath('/Country/Location/text()', penDetails) LIKE '%\_%' ESCAPE '\'
```

You can also use a different escape character if you want:

```
AND CAST(xpath('/Country/Location/text()', penDetails) LIKE '%#_%' ESCAPE '#'
```